# Select no Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

estou tentando fazer uma query no sequelize mas não estou obtendo sucesso. Preciso fazer a busca de um colaborador no banco pela usa matrícula. Porém o colaborador deve ser do mesmo setor que o gestor logado no sistema. O setorId do gestor é req.user.id

Assim está o meu código

```
await Colaborador.findOne({
            include: [{
              model: Cargo,
            },
            {
                model: Setor,
                where:{
                    setorId: req.user.setorId
                }
            }
             ]
          },{
              where:{
                  matricula: matriculaId
              }
          })
```

Também preciso fazer um inner join com as tabelas cargo e setor para aparecer na tela. O sequelize não está me retornando este funcionário procurado. Qual seria o meu erro?

Eu consegui fazer pelo SQL puro, porém gostaria de fazer pelo Sequelize mesmo.

Com o sql puro fica assim:

```
let colaborador = await sequelize.query(`SELECT c.colaboradorId, c.nome as nomeColaborador, g.nome as nomeCargo ,s.nome as nomeSetor FROM colaborador c, setor s, cargo g WHERE c.setorId = s.setorId AND  c.cargoId = g.cargoId AND c.setorId = ${req.user.setorId} AND c.matricula = ${matriculaId} LIMIT 1`, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender como funciona o `find` do Sequelize, explicarei equivalentes ao seu código SQL:

```sql
SELECT c.colaboradorId, c.nome as nomeColaborador, g.nome as nomeCargo ,s.nome as nomeSetor
    FROM colaborador c, setor s, cargo g
    WHERE c.setorId = s.setorId
        AND c.cargoId = g.cargoId
        AND c.setorId = ${req.user.setorId}
        AND c.matricula = ${matriculaId}
    LIMIT 1
```

### Etapas

1. **`LIMIT 1`:** Você fez corretamente, a função [`findOne()`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html#-code-findone--code-) do Sequelize serve para isso.
2. **Atributos:** caso não deseje um `SELECT *`, você deve indicar os atributos em um array [`attributes`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries), e os atributos das associações (`Cargo` e `Setor`) devem ser definidos no objeto do `include`, por exemplo:

```js
Colaborador.findOne({
    attributes: ['attr1', 'attr2'],
    include: [{
        model: Modelo1,
        attributes: ['attr1_do_modelo1']
    }]
});
```

3. **`JOIN`**: No seu SQL, você representou `WHERE c.setorId = s.setorId AND c.cargoId = g.cargoId`, que podemos substituir por um `JOIN`. O `JOIN` é realizado no [`include`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html) do Sequelize, onde o ORM identifica através da *Foreign Key* declarada no modelo por qual atributo deve procurar, então fica assim:

```js
Colaborador.findOne({
    include: [{
        // Aqui o Sequelize já sabe que o Setor está associado ao Colaborador
        // pelos atributos Colaborador.setorId e Setor.setorId
        model: Setor
    }]
});
```

4. **`WHERE`:** Falta o código para o `WHERE c.setorId = ${req.user.setorId} AND c.matricula = ${matriculaId}`. Você pode usar um [`where`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses) comum do `find`:

```js
Colaborador.findOne({
    where: {
        setorId: req.user.setorId,
        matricula: matriculaId
    }
});
```

### Resultado

```js
Colaborador.findOne({
    attributes: ['colaboradorId', 'nome'],
    include: [
        {
            model: Cargo,
            attributes: ['nome']
        },
        {
            model: Setor,
            attributes: ['nome']
        }
    ],
    where: {
        setorId: req.user.setorId,
        matricula: matriculaId
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou muito bem!!! Agora surgiu uma outra dúvida, e se caso o campo do where estiver relacionado a uma tabela do Include? setorId esta na tabela colaborador, agora imagine que eu preciso de um atributo da tabela Cargo que está no include e colocar uma condição?

Comment: Não sei dizer ao certo agora porque nunca o fiz, mas existe um exemplo parecido no SOen, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39062925/8839059). O exemplo em questão é sobre um atributo de outra tabela (B) com um valor fixo (e não comparando com um valor da tabela A). Creio que essa é uma dúvida pertinente e pode virar outra questão aqui no SO, se já não existir

Comment: Achei [esse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779149/8839059) também. Acho que serviria ao seu caso, não tenho certeza